We are looking for an up to date source for pill images per NDC
We are trying to find an up to date source for pill images per NDC. I'm aware the NLM retired it (https://datadiscovery.nlm.nih.gov/Drugs-and-Chemicals/Pillbox-retired-January-28-2021-/crzr-uvwg/about_data)
However, i'm wondering if there is another source we can find them that is still accessible and still being updated at no cost.
